# Plotly: I cannot use Trendline

Tags: python, plotly

```
fig = px.scatter(companies_dates["AAPL"], x="date", y=["SMA_fast", "SMA_slow"], trendline="ols")
fig.update_traces(mode = "lines")
fig.show()
```

The Errormessage is:

```
ValueError: Could not convert value of 'x' ('date') into a numeric type.
If 'x' contains stringified dates, please convert to a datetime column.
```

expample of my df:

```
date    open    close   SMA_fast    SMA_slow    RSI
```

0   2021-12-31  178.089996  177.570007  162.098 143.954 52.8347

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXtTb.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please show an example of your df and a minimal example of your complete code that loads it and does this graphing.

Comment: I believe that converting the x-axis to date format will eliminate the error. `companies_dates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(companies_dates['date'])`

Comment: the error got eleminated, but the trendline looks kinda wrong :c I posted a picture of the Graph

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using a **plotly** sample dataset and making it compatible with your code.  *date* as `datetime` works for lines and trend lines.   Randomising order does not do effect you have provided in your image.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_apple_stock.csv"
).rename(columns={"AAPL_x": "date", "AAPL_y": "SMA_fast"})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["SMA_slow"] = df["SMA_fast"] * np.random.uniform(0.85, 0.9, len(df))
# partially randomize order,  just messes up line not trandline
# df = df.iloc[np.random.permutation(25).tolist() + df.index.tolist()[25:]]
companies_dates = {"AAPL": df}

fig = px.scatter(
    companies_dates["AAPL"], x="date", y=["SMA_fast", "SMA_slow"], trendline="ols"
)
fig.update_traces(mode="lines")
fig.show()
```

[image]